# parse string and store elements to an array

Tags: javascript

I have a string likes below

```
a_b_c_d
```

I hope to decode it to an array t as

```
t[0]->a
t[1]->b    
t[2]->c
t[3]->d
```

Just wonder if there ia function of javascript can parse the string directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = "a_b_c_d";
var t = string.split('_');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bHs4C/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string

```
var t = "a_b_c_d".split("_");
```